# Python to combine multiple lines in a txt file if certain criteria match

Tags: python, text-files

Could someone help me to combine multiple lines in txt file into a single line if text between   tags is not in a single line already?

my.txt

```
<start>Hello World.</start>
<start>Hello World, this is my message.


Regards,

Jane

www.url.com

</start>
```

desired output.txt:

```
<start>Hello World.</start>
<start>Hello World, this is my message. Regards, Jane www.url.com</start>
```

my code so far:

```
f = open('/path/to/my.txt', 'r')
currentline = ""
for line in f:
    if line.startswith('<start>'):
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        print(line)
    else:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        currentline = currentline + line
        print (currentline)

f.close()
```

output:

```
<start>Hello World.</start>
<start>Hello World, this is my message.


Regards,
Regards,
Regards,Jane
Regards,Jane
Regards,Janewww.url.com
Regards,Janewww.url.com
Regards,Janewww.url.com</start>
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: Just at a quick glance I think your problems are: 
1. You are not saving the beginning the the line to current if it .startswith('<start>') BUT doesn't endswith('</start>').
2. You print out he current_line every time. You want to only print our current_line when you find </start>

It may be better to build what you are looking and than print it out after the loop, just for clarity in your code. Unless of course you need the live output.

Just try and rework your print logic a bit and you've got it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import re

with open('/path/to/my.txt', 'r') as fin:
    text = fin.read()

pattern = r"(<start>(.|\n)*?</start>)"
output = []
for utter in re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE):
    output.append(re.sub("\n+", ' ', utter[0]))
print(output)
#['<start>Hello World.</start>',
# '<start>Hello World, this is my message. Regards, Jane www.url.com </start>']
```

Comment: Hi Anwarvic, thanks for your help! however, when I run this it tells me that ' text' is not defined. Should I put in this place path to my txt file? thanks in advance!

Comment: Updated my answer